# Mouseover event works fine, but once

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm new to JavaScript, so please help.

I have made a image hover in CSS, but I need to add interaction in content to this hover. So, I used JavaScript. It works as I wanted but only once, I have to refresh browser. [Here is a CodePen which shows how it works.](http://codepen.io/gilek555/pen/vXmpkP)

Also code:

```js
var content = document.getElementById('fav-project-content');
var imgContent = document.getElementById('fav-project-img');

imgContent.addEventListener('mouseover', rev);
imgContent.addEventListener('mouseout', hid);

function rev() {
  if (content.className === "hide") {
    content.className = "";
  }
  TweenMax.from(content, 0.5, {
    x: 1500,
    opacity: 0,
    ease: Quad.easeOut
  });
};

function hid() {
  TweenMax.to(content, 0.5, {
    x: 1500,
    opacity: 0,
    ease: Quad.easeOut
  });
};
```

```css
.content {
  margin-top: 19vw;
  margin-bottom: 5vw;
}
#fav-project-img {
  background-image: url(http://dannnk.com/test/images/spiro-bw.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 578px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.78, .54, .47, .88);
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.78, .54, .47, .88);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.78, .54, .47, .88);
}
#fav-project-img:hover {
  background-image: url(http://dannnk.com/test/images/spiro.jpg);
  width: 42%;
  margin-left: -1%;
}
#fav-project-content {
  background-color: #f7f0e8;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 59%;
  height: 578px;
}
#fav-project-content.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="fav-project-img"></div>
  <div id="fav-project-content" class="hide"></div>
</div>
```

As I wrote, I'm new to JavaScript. Probably, here it's problem with my code. Can you show me what is wrong?

Comment: Works multiple times for me. What browser do you use? (I've tried in Vivaldi)

Comment: Image hover works multiple times but this space on the left works only once for me on Safari, Chrome and Firefox...

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me.
btw you can achieve the same without javascript.
Use css, and style your image container and image with the :hover selector, for the animatios you can use transition properties.
example:

```
.image-container{
  transition: all .3s ease;
  width: 200px;
}
.image-container:hover{
  width: auto;
}
.image{
  -webkit-filter: saturation(0);
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.image-container:hover .image{
  -webkit-filter: saturation(1);
}
```

Comment: Really? This box on left side of image animating multiple times? For me working only once on Safari, Chrome and Firefox...

Comment: Yep, it's working. Check the console, maybe there's an error from another script stopping this one